# Win7 C++ application always reserving at least 4k memory per allocation

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I'm currently looking into memory consumption issues of a C++ application that I have written (a rendering engine using OpenGL) and have stumbled upon a rather unusual problem:
I'm using my own allocators basically everywhere in the system, which all obtain their memory from a default allocator which is using `malloc()`/`free()` for the actual memory.

It turns out that my application is always reserving at least 4096 bytes (the page size on my system) for every allocation through malloc(), even if the size is significantly smaller. 
`malloc(8)` or even `malloc(1)` both result in an increase of memory of 4096 bytes. I'm tracking the used memory size through [GetProcessMemoryInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms683219(v=vs.85).aspx) directly before and after the allocation, as well as through the TaskManager (which basically shows the same values). Interestingly, using `_msize(ptr)` returns the correct size of the pointer.

I can only reproduce this behaviour within my own application, testing it with a new VS2012 C++ project did not yield the same results. This behaviour also seems independent of the current reserved size of the application, even with more than 10GB of free RAM it always reserves at least 4K per allocation.

I have no deep knowledge of the innards of the Windows operating system (if it is at all related to the OS), so if anyone has an idea what could cause this behaviour I would be greatful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be running with "full page heap"... a diagnostic mode to help more quickly catch memory access errors in your code.

Comment: This was indeed the answer, I forgot that I had configured the Application Verifier for my executable a while ago. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Check this, it's from 1993 :-)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810603.aspx

*This does not mean that the smallest amount of memory that can be allocated in a heap is 4096 bytes; rather, the heap manager commits pages of memory as needed to satisfy specific allocation requests. If, for example, an application allocates 100 bytes via a call to GlobalAlloc, the heap manager allocates a 100-byte chunk of memory within its committed region for this request. If there is not enough committed memory available at the time of the request, the heap manager simply commits another page to make the memory available.*

Comment: This would explain it if the memory would increase by 4K after multiple allocations, however in my case it is increasing for every allocation, even multiple succeeding small ones, like 'for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) malloc(1); //Ignore the leaks' increases the memory consumption by ~400K. The article mentions some overhead per allocation, but it should not be 4K per allocation of 1 byte?